# Tensoring and Hom functors preserve multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. Let $M$ be a left $R$-module. For $r \in Z(R)$ the map $m^M_r: M \to M, x \mapsto rx$ is $R$-linear. A functor $F: \text{R-Mod} \to \text{R-Mod}$ preserves multiplication, if $F(m^M_r) = m^{F(M)}_r$ for all left $R$-modules $M$ and all $r \in Z(R)$.

Why does for an $(R,R)$-bimodule $M$ the Hom-functor $\text{Hom}(M,\cdot): \text{R-Mod} \to \text{R-Mod}$ preserve multiplication?

It is for $a \in M$ and an left $R$-module $N$
$$\text{Hom}(M,m^N_r)(\varphi)(a) = m^N_r\circ\varphi(a) = r\varphi(a) = \varphi(ra) \text{ and } (r\cdot\varphi)(a) = \varphi(ar),$$
but $ar \neq ra$ even for $r \in Z(R)$ in general? So, I think, $\text{Hom}(M,m^N_r) \neq m^{\text{Hom}(M,N)}_r$ in general. For the tensor functor it is the same problem with $ar \neq ra$.

In Rotman, An Introduction to Homological Algebra, on page 345 before Proposition 6.18 it is claimed, that tensoring and Hom functors preserve multiplication.

Comment: @DaniëlApol I think for non-commutative rings the map $(r\Phi)(a) := r \Phi(a)$ is not $R$-linear because $(r\Phi)(\lambda a) := r \Phi(\lambda a) = r\lambda \Phi( a) \neq \lambda r\Phi( a) = \lambda (r\Phi)( a)$ in general. So, in general, there would be no $R$-module structure induced by the left-module structure on the codomains.

Comment: You're right, I was being stupid.

Comment: At least we know for central $r\in Z(R)$ that $a\mapsto\phi(ra)$ is genuinely $R$-linear. I would expect that this is what's implicitly going on in any applications, but it's not great...

Comment: @FShrike But to define the functor R-Mod $\to$ R-Mod we need an $(R,R)$-bimodule and not an $(R,Z(R))$-module